# How to parse a multi dimensional array to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I am trying to post a multi-dimensional array to php but I am having no luck.
My array is created in Javascript which contains arrays/objects and in each array is an associated value such as it is done
in this function:

```
function mouseUp(e) {
    startX = 0;
    startY = 0;
    endX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    endY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    width = 30;
    height = 30;
    filler = "#FFFFFF";
    filler = "#FFFF00";
    //send these vars over and push them into an array
    addRect(startX, startY, width, height, filler, border);
} //end on mouse up

function addRect(startx, starty, endX, endY, color1, bc) {

    newArray2 = [{
        x: startx,
        y: starty,
        x1: endX,
        y1: endY,
        color: color1,
        borderColor: bc
    }];
    arrayBig.push(newArray2);

    //console.log(arrayBig);
}
```

I use this function to target the input value like:

```
function send() {

    var elem = document.getElementById("rectangle");
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(arrayBig);
    elem.value = myJSON;
}
```

My html form is this:

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
<input name="rectangle[][]" id="rectangle" type="hidden" class="valueFields" value=""/>
<input name="parseMe" type="hidden" value="layout" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="submitButton" value="send" onclick="send()"/>
</form>
```

Now I am having trouble in this part assigning the array values to vars in PHP here:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['parseMe'])) {
    if ($_POST['parseMe'] == "layout") {
        print_r($_POST['rectangle']);
$myObj= json_decode($POST['rectangle'],true);
echo $myObj['color'];
        //how to assign each value to a variable here???
        //$x = rectangle[0][0].color; //doesn't work
    }
}
?>
```

If anyone can show me how to parse this properly I thank you in advance.
In Javascript all I need to do to assign the value to a var is this:
     c = arrayBig[0][0].color;

But how do I do this line of code in PHP?
Also would the input name look like name="rectangle[]" or name="rectangle[][]" ?

Comment: ok like this  addRect(startX,startY, width, height, filler, border);   startX =30; and startY =3 and so on.

Comment: I only use javascript and canvas for this but not css

Comment: so the values are passed into the addRect function that pushes it into the array .

Comment: Oh I am using it on a MouseUp function. So basically you draw a rectangle and then I am asking how do I send this array of coordinates so I can use them in Php.I could update that in the above question.

Comment: How about pass value by JSON.stringify(array) in js and json_decode($array) in php?

Comment: Ok. I was thinking that I might have to use JSON for this but wasnt sure. I think I know how to do that...

Comment: Thanks for advice. so do you think that is the only way to get it to php or is that the best way?

Comment: But I am still confused after using json once the string gets to php. How do encode them? like this: $myObj -> color

Comment: $myObj = json_decode($recivedString, true); will do the work for you. After that you will access elements like : $myObj['color'];

Comment: I get a warning json decode expects parameter 1 to be string. Did I miss something?

Comment: ``foreach($array as $key => $value) {${$key} = $value;}`` something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found what you are searching for.

after form transfer your post array looks like that:

`$_POST['rectangle'] = "[{\"startx\": \"1\", \"starty\": \"2\"}]"`

i think after this short script you will say how easy it was:

```
$jsonString = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rectangle');
$objectArray = json_decode($jsonString);
foreach($objectArray as $key => $singleObject){
  echo $singleObject->startx; // output is 1
  echo $singleObject->starty; // output is 2
);
```

Comment: I have tried this answer. Yes my array looks like that after stringfly except the start = Array (   [0] => Array    (  [0] => [[{\"x\":80,\"y\":84,\"x1\":183,..... Could you please explain what $objectString is here because when I use this snippet I get a different warning saying invalid argument supplied for foreach(). I am unable to access the values still..Thanks for any more help you can give me.

Comment: ``<input name="rectangle[][]" id="rectangle" type="hidden" class="valueFields" value=""/>`` makes the different. change it to ``name="rectangle"``. what you have is jsonString in array in array in postarray bacause of your name is array in array. $objectString is replaced with $jsonString

Comment: Awesome! it works now. Thanks. Just had to modify the code like $singleObject[0]->color; and put a curly brace at the end but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

and i found 1 more:

```
function addRect(startx, starty, endX, endY, color1, bc) {

    newArray2 = [{
        x: startx,
        y: starty,
        x1: endX,
        y1: endY,
        color: color1,
        borderColor: bc
    }];
    arrayBig.push(newArray2);
    // looks like [[{...}], [{...}]]

    //console.log(arrayBig);
}
```

if you change newArray2 to be an object and not an array with object inside your result will be more readable:

```
function addRect(startx, starty, endX, endY, color1, bc) {
  var rectangle = {
    x: startx,
    y: starty,
    x1: endX,
    y1: endY,
    color: color1,
    borderColor: bc
  }

  arrayBig.push(rectangle);
  // looks like [{...}, {...}]
}
```